# Phalcon Routing exclude Routing to Controllers when File Exists

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-routing

I have some css .map files directly under assets folder, however for some reason they failed to load and i get a 404 error in the dispatcher and router. Any solution on how to fix this issue ? i added following config to the router but still get the error.

```
$router->add(
    '/assets/css/dashboard-free.css.map'
);
```

Error log says

```
example.com/assets/css/dashboard-free.css.map: 
2019-02-13 07:02:58: 
Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher\Exception: IndexController handler class cannot be loaded
 File=/var/.../Module.php
 Line=27
#0 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher->_throwDispatchException('IndexController...', 2)
#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->dispatch()
#2 /var/.../Module.php(27): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()
#3 /var/.../web/index.php(12): Admin\Module->main()
#4 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Apache

Try this in your `.htaccess` file

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(bmp|css|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|js|png|svgz?|webp|webmanifest)$ $1.$3 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

### nginx

```
location ~* (.+)\.(?:\w+)\.(bmp|css|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|m?js|png|svgz?|webp|webmanifest)$ {
  try_files $uri $1.$2;
}
```

Comment: i am using nginx. Also i would prefer to solve this without doing server configuration. Within the code itself

Comment: I don't think you can do that, unless you put a really long `if` statement in your `index.php` which is the starting point of your app to ignore those files and stream them straight to the client. In either case it will be costly in terms of processing for you vs. letting the web server do that.

Comment: With the router you can also use some "smart" regex to detect these files (css/js etc) and forward all those requests to one controller/action which in turn will send the response immediately back to the caller. Still, you will be wasting cycles.

Comment: I added the nginx example.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think this has anything to do with phalcon or php
i would check the css file for the map path

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=dashboard-free.css.map */
```